# How to define the constant for the module in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a list of constants that i want to use for the every view i have and i also used these in the constants in controller is it possible.

Comment: i want this all should work in the module that i  created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define constant in file using `const` keyword.

```
const TRANSACTION_COMPLETE = '1';
const TRANSACTION_PENDING = '2';
const PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'trans_email/ident_sales';
```

You can call all const using **self** keyword.
**`self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY`**
**`self::TRANSACTION_COMPLETE`**
**`self::TRANSACTION_PENDING`**

You can call constant in anyfile also you can use inside controller file.

Comment: which file i can use to define all these constants.

Comment: you can call inside any file. you have to define constant in all file where you have really need

Comment: if i need constant in controller first of all i must define them like this in the controller file.    const FLAG= '1' ;   then used that in the controller.

Comment: yes this is the correct, you can call like self::FLAG

Comment: you have to need this flag in other file then you can call like this, \Vendor\Module\Controller\FileName::FLAG, first pass your file path then call const flag

Answer (score 0):

Constants that are used in a single class, such as a controller, should be defined in that class. Constants that relate to a specific model should be on that model's Model class, even if they are used by other classes.

Constants that are not specific to a model, or relate to models defined in dependency modules, I prefer to define in the module's `Api/` directory. Constants, like Interfaces, define a common point to be accessed and so should be found in a similar location.